# why check null object did not work in react

Tags: javascript

Now I am using this code the check if result is null then return:

```
let data = this.props.channel.channel;
        if(!data || data == {} || data == undefined){
            return (<div></div>);
        }
```

but from my debug output seems it did not work, what should I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: `data == {}` doesn't make any sense. It will be `false` no matter what because objects are compared by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming to check for an empty object, you can use this:

```js
Object.keys(data).length // outputs 0 if object is empty
```

This converts the object keys to an array, which you can then use to check how many items the object had.

More info on `Object.keys()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 1):

`data == {}` doesn't make any sense. It will be `false` no matter what because objects are compared by reference.

If you need to check for an empty object, you have several methods at your disposal:

```
JSON.stringify(data) === '{}'
```

or

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).length === 0 // will also count non-enumerable properties!
```

or

```
Object.keys(data).length === 0
```